# I get an error in fileSystem module while using writeFile Asynchronously

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use `writeFile()` inside call back function of `readFile()` from `fileSystem` module..

I'm a beginner in node.js I have been watching Youtube tutorials

```
const fs = require('fs');   

fs.readFile('readMe.txt','utf8', function(err, data){  

  fs.writeFile('writeMe.txt', data);
});
console.log('Fire..');
```

I get an error pasted below.. I don't understand the type of this error.. can someone help me with this?

```
Fire..!
fs.js:128
  throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK();
  ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
    at maybeCallback (fs.js:128:9)
    at Object.writeFile (fs.js:1163:14)
    at C:\Users\shahzaib laptops\Desktop\NodeJS\pathModule\fileSystem.js:6:6
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)
```

Comment: Did u got a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the Following snippet to read and write file what need. You this in common and use this if u need in many place. u need to pass the filename to read and write to this method.
>
> Else directly use the callback alone the parameter in method and jsut give the file name static as u have above.

```
public ReadandWriteFile(fileNameToRead, fileNameToWrite, callback) {
        fs.readFile(fileNameToRead, "utf-8", (err, data) => {
            if (err) { console.log(err) }
            if (data) {
                fs.writeFile(fileNameToWrite, data, (err) => {
                    if (err) { console.log(err) };
                    if (data) {
                        callback({ message: 'Successfully Written to File.' })
                    }
                });
            }
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add proper err handling and callback Fn. in writefile

```
const fs = require('fs');   

fs.readFile('readMe.txt','utf8', function(err, data){  
  if(err) callback or return err
  else{
     fs.writeFile('writeMe.txt', data,'utf8', function(err2, data2){
         if(err2) callback or return err2
         else console.log(data2)
     });

  }
});
console.log('Fire..');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use promise for readFile and writeFile.

```
const fsPromises = require("fs").promises;
async function readAndWrite() {
  let filehandle;
  try {
    filehandle = await fsPromises.readFile("readMe.txt");
    console.log(filehandle);
    let writeComleted = await fsPromises.writeFile("writeMe.txt", filehandle);
  } catch {
    throw new Error("something bad happened");
  }
}

readAndWrite();
```